# What method is called when a push notification is accepted?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm trying to perform some task when a user gets a push notification and presses VIEW. I don't want the app to just launch like it normally does, I want to perform some other task.

What method gets called when the user gets a push and presses VIEW?? didFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't seem to get called (not on iPhone 4 anyways).

I basically want something to happen when a user presses VIEW, and only when they press VIEW.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is not being called?  Normally you can tell that your app was launched from the user clicking on the view button of a remote push notification by inspecting the `launchOptions` parameter.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];  
    if (pushInfo)  
    {
        // app was launched from a remote push notification
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm telling it to show an alert view whenever it calls didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, works fine on iPhone 3 but not iPhone 4

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```